blank gitlab pages after deployment
I want to deploy my vite repo to gitlab pages,but I`m getting a blank page, my CI/CD pipeline:
# .gitlab-ci.yml 
variables:
  GIT_VERSION: $(git describe --tags --always --dirty)

stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  - versioning

build site:
  image: node:20-alpine3.18
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: node:20-alpine3.18
  script:
    - npm install --global http-server
    - http-server ./public -p $PORT &
  environment:
   name: production
  only:
    - main
    - devel

pages:
  image: node:latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run build
    - mv public public-vue
    - mv dist public
    - find public -type f -regex '.*\.\(htm\|html\|txt\|text\|js\|css\)$' -exec gzip -f -k {} \;
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - main
    - devel

versioning:
  stage: versioning
  image: node:20-alpine3.18
  script:
    - echo "VERSION=$GIT_VERSION" > version.env
    - echo "VERSION_TAG=$(echo $GIT_VERSION | cut -d '-' -f 1)" >> version.env
    - npm version --no-git-tag-version $VERSION_TAG
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: version.env

my index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? '/' + process.env.CI_PROJECT_NAME + '/'
      : '/'
  }


